# RuntimeError: Unsupported image type, must be 8bit gray or RGB image

Tags: python

I use the following program:

```
import dlib
import os
import numpy as np
from skimage import io


sp = dlib.shape_predictor('shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat')
face_rec = \
    dlib.face_recognition_model_v1('dlib_face_recognition_resnet_model_v1.dat')
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()


def get_face_descriptor(x):
    img = io.imread('jpg/'+x)
    detected_faces = detector(img, 1)
    q = 0
    for k, d in enumerate(detected_faces):
        shape = sp(img, d)
        try:
            q += 1
            f = face_rec.compute_face_descriptor(img, shape)
            mas = np.array(f)
            file_name_ = 'npy/' + x.replace('.jpg', '')
            np.save(file_name_ + '_' + str(q), mas)
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)


files = os.listdir('jpg')
z = 0
for x in files: 
    z += 1
    file_name = 'npy/' + (x.replace('.jpg', ''))
    if not os.path.exists(file_name + '_1.npy'):
        print(z)
        get_face_descriptor(x)
```

Successfully removes biometric data from the first 40,000 photos, and then gets up with the error RuntimeError: Unsupported image type, must be 8bit gray or RGB image. I will be grateful for your help!

Comment: It seems like a very clear error. Have you tried investigating which image is causing it?

Comment: I was afraid that this problem was caused by a separate image. I have one million of them) Well, I'll look for it.

Comment: you could change the code so that the code tells you which one has the error. maybe also you want the code to continue on the rest of the images even if it finds an error?